# How to check two array of objects property using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to return true or false based on two array objects
property using javascript

If arrobj1 and arrobj2 `value` and `country` same return true

I have tried below, may i know better way to do using javascript

```
Tried

for(var elem of arrobj1){
 const result = arrobj2.filter(obj => obj.value === elem.value && obj.country === elem.country);
 if(result.length > 0){
 return true;
}
}

var arrobj1 =[
  {id:1, name: "one", value:"sales", country:"MY"},
  {id:2, name: "two", value:"finance", country:"PH"},
  {id:3, name: "three", value:"digital", country:"SL"}
]

var arrobj2 =[
 {id:4, name: "four", value:"digital", country:"SL"}
]

Expected Output
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your code to start with the arrays then the sorting function

**arrobj2 should be:**

```
 var arrobj2 =[
 {id:4, name: "four", value:"digital", country:"SL"}
]
```

**instead of:**

```
var arrobj2 =[{
 {id:4, name: "four", value:"digital", country:"SL"}
}]
```

also try *console.log('true')* instead if *return true*. You'll notice something that would help you later

Answer (score 0):

- Your code works perfectly. To use the `return` keyword, you have to wrap your code in a function and call it when needed.

Try this

```js
var arrobj1 = [
    {id:1, name: "one", value:"sales", country:"MY"},
    {id:2, name: "two", value:"finance", country:"PH"},
    {id:3, name: "three", value:"digital", country:"SL"}
]

var arrobj2 = [
    {id:4, name: "four", value:"digital", country:"SL"}
];

function exist(arrobj1, arrobj2){
    for(var elem of arrobj1){
        const result = arrobj2.filter(obj => obj.value === elem.value && obj.country === elem.country);
        if(result.length > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(exist(arrobj1, arrobj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as follows:

```js
const 
arrobj1 =[ {id:1, name: "one", value:"sales", country:"MY"}, {id:2, name: "two", value:"finance", country:"PH"}, {id:3, name: "three", value:"digital", country:"SL"} ], 
arrobj2 =[ {id:4, name: "four", value:"digital", country:"SL"} ],

found = arrobj2.some(
    ({value:v,country:c}) => 
    arrobj1.map(
        ({value,country}) => `${value}|${country}`
    ).includes(`${v}|${c}`)
);

console.log( found );
```